# How to get the difference between next and previous row in an R time series?

Tags: r, time-series, diff, difference

I have a quite large time series comprising around 14k observations of 4 variables (`date`, `x`, `y`, `z`).

How can I, (contrary to the function `diff( df$vector, lag = 1)` which computes the difference between the current value (`t`) and the previous one (`t-1`)),   calculate for each value the difference between the next value (`t+1`) and the previous value (`t-1`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to understand the request... Generate some data:

```
set.seed(11)
a = sample(1:10, 10)
```

Data is given as:

```
3  1  5  9  7  8  6  4  2 10
```

Need `T+1 vs. T-1`:

```
T = 0 => No computation
T = 1 => 5 - 3 = 2
T = 2 => 9 - 1 = 8
...
T = 9 => 10 - 4 = 6
T = 10 => No computation
```

With that being established...

```
#' Future Difference
#' 
#' Obtain the lagged difference between X[t+1+lag] - X[t-1-lag]
#' @param x   A \code{vec}
#' @param lag A \code{integer} indicating the lag
#' @return A \code{vec} with differences taken at T+lag v. T-lag
#' @examples
#' set.seed(11)
#' a = sample(1:10, 12)
#' fdiff(a)
fdiff = function(x, lag = 1){
  # Number of obs
  n = length(x)

  # Trigger error to prevent subset
  if(n < 2+lag){stop("`x` must be greater than `2+lag`")}

  # X_(T+1) - X_(T-1)
  x[(2+lag):n] - x[1:(n-lag-1)]
}
```

Calling it on `a` gives:

```
fdiff(a)

2  8  2 -1 -1 -4 -4  6
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, all you want is to set lag = 2.

Comment: hm no, lag = 2 computes the difference between current value t and t-2. 

I need to get the difference between t+1 and t-1

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `diff` of 2 ! (You should use `diff` not `lag` as suggested by @Kake_Fisk.) Using the data from the accepted answer from @Coatless:

```
set.seed(11)
a = sample(1:10, 10)
diff(a,2)
```

gives:

```
[1]  2  8  2 -1 -1 -4 -4  6
```

edit after comment from OP:

If I understand your comment correctly your accepted answer from @coatless does not give you what you were asking for. You are looking for a series which gives you the previous and next differences of each element to it's neighbours. So the length of this series has to be 2 times minus 2 ( as the first element has no previous value and the last one no next value ) of the original series. 
One possible solution might be:

```
set.seed(11)
a = sample(1:10, 10)
a
[1]  3  1  5  9  7  8  6  4  2 10

prev <- a[1:(length(a)-1)] - a[2:length(a)] # series of previous values
nxt <- -1 * prev # series of next values

nextPrevValues <- rep(0,2 * (length(a)-1))
for(i in 1:length(a)-1){
  nextPrevValues[2*i-1] <- nxt[i]
  nextPrevValues[2*i] <- prev[i]
}
```

Starting with the difference from the first element to the next you get the previous and next differences for each element. The last element only has a previous value.

```
nextPrevValues
 [1] -2  2  4 -4  4 -4 -2  2  1 -1 -2  2 -2  2 -2  2  8 -8
```

Comment: R interprets `diff(a,2)` as `diff(a, lag=2)`. I get the same results : 


`set.seed(11)
a=sample(1:10, 10)

a
 [1]  3  1  5  9  7  8  6  4  2 10
diff(a, 2)
[1]  6  6  3 -3 -3 -6  4
diff(a,lag=2)
[1]  6  6  3 -3 -3 -6  4 `

Comment: That's the point. Kake_Fisk suggests `lag' which is incorrect and the accepted answer is correct but unnecessarily complicated by constructing a function which is already available in base R.

Comment: OK i got it ! `diff(a, lag=2)`and returns the difference between `t`and `t-2`, but i can fix it by setting an offset and the beginning of the array : `c(NA, diff(a,2))`