# comparing previous and next rows and setting a condition

Tags: r

I would like to compare previous and next rows for given row. I used `diff` function for this purpose but unfortunately it does not give what I need. Similar post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895525/how-to-get-the-difference-between-next-and-previous-row-in-an-r-time-series) but my post is rather looking for something different!

Here is what I mean

```
test = data.frame(y1=c(10,22,22,36,36,36,38),
                      y2=c(12,22,18,21,14,17,15))  

> test
  y1 y2
1 10 12
2 22 22
3 22 18
4 36 21
5 36 14
6 36 17
7 38 15
```

and I tried

```
test%>%
mutate(diff_y1=c(NA,diff(y1)))

  y1 y2 diff_y1
1 10 12      NA
2 22 22      12
3 22 18       0
4 36 21      14
5 36 14       0
6 36 17       0
7 38 15       2
```

What I want to have is that assigning same difference number if there is consecutive row next of previous of that row. See that the `diff` function gives different `diff_y1` values. Its normal. What I want add is that setting same diff value if the first row that starts a consecutive row.

If row i and i+1 or i and i-1 are the same I want a 0 on row i and i+1 or i and i-1.

Something like this is the expected output

```
      y1 y2 diff_y1
    1 10 12      NA
    2 22 22       0
    3 22 18       0
    4 36 21       0
    5 36 14       0
    6 36 17       0
    7 38 15       2
```

Comment: Your statement is not clear.

Comment: @Onyambu I edited the OP little bit. Could you tell me which part is not clear?

Comment: I do not understand your assigning procedure. Why do you have a bunch of zeros then a 2? What is the logic you are using to assign a 0 in row 4 or a zero in row 2?

Comment: the `diff` function subtracts the previous value from the current value. I do understand that, and it gives what you claim is the wrong output. So what is the logic you are using to obtain the expected output?

Comment: @Onyambu Ok. see that the `diff` function gives different `diff_y1` values. Its normal. What I want add is that setting same diff value if the first row that starts a consecutive row. like 22 22 they are consecutive so I want to be have them same diff_y1 value but using another function maybe ?

Comment: Do you mean : If row i and i+1 are the same you want a 0 on row i and i+1 ?

Comment: @MaxFt Exactly!!

Comment: @MaxFt or i and i-1 are the same want a 0 on row i and i-1.

Comment: Let me know if my answer works for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If row i and i+1 are the same you want a 0 on row i and i+1.

We first apply the diff r function.
Whenever the difference is 0 at row i it means that the "difference" at row i-1 should also be set to 0.

```
customdiff <- function(x){
  res<-c(NA,diff(x))
  res[which(res==0)-1]=0
  res
}

test%>%
  mutate(diff_y1=customdiff(y1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! you saved my day! Really appreciated! Just one thing how can I learn to write function like you ?

Comment: Pratice.. There is no shortcut or tutorial that will get you there I think. I spent months debugging and improving my own code. You will get there eventually. =) 
Keep in mind that every problem you encounter will come up again and again and again. My only advice would be solve every single coding problem as rigorously as possible no matter how important is the issue. It pays very quickly. Also, StackOverflow is of great support you are lucky to have landed here early!

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide an alternative, you could use the phantastic `dplyr` package, especially `case_when()`, `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
library(dplyr)
test = data.frame(y1=c(10,22,22,36,36,36,38),
                  y2=c(12,22,18,21,14,17,15))
test %>%
  mutate(prev_ = lag(y1),                 # the previous item
         next_ = lead(y1),                # the next item
         diff_y1 = case_when(             # ifelse 
           y1 == next_ | y1 == prev_ ~ 0,
           TRUE ~ y1-prev_
         )) %>%
  select(-prev_,-next_)                   # deselect prev & next
```

Which yields

```
  y1 y2 diff_y1
1 10 12      NA
2 22 22       0
3 22 18       0
4 36 21       0
5 36 14       0
6 36 17       0
7 38 15       2
```

Comment: thanks Jan. Its great to have another way to look at the data.